# SQL - Convert one-to-many into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a solution in SQL Server to convert a result into another format based on this example.

Basic query result

```
ID     Name     Other IDs
-------------------------
1      John     22
2      Joe      r15
2      Joe      12
3      Jim      17
3      Jim      r87
```

Into

```
ID      Name     UniqueID      StudentID
----------------------------------------
1       John     22            
2       Joe      12            r15
3       Jim      17            r87
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hopefully your first query is already the result of multiple normalized tables. If so, you can write a new query easily which is based on those tables instead of the first query. If not, then the real problem is your database is not properly modeled.

Comment: quite strange question, what have u tried so far?

Comment: Describe how to chose UniqueID and StudentID. And show us your current query!

Comment: Are there id's other than UniqueID and StudentID? How can you tell that 12 is UniqueID, and r15 is StudentID?

Comment: It's the result of an query from 2 tables (Person,  PersonIdentifications)
Person had ID and Name fields
PersonIdentifications has OtherID and Type (studentid/employeeid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do suspect you can have different rules to decide if an ID is the UniqueId or the StudentID. From your data I tried this:

```
  select [ID],
         [Name],
         max(case isnumeric([Other IDs]) when 1 then [Other IDs] end) UniqueID,
         max(case left([Other IDs],1) when 'r' then [Other IDs] end) StudentID
    from Table1
group by [ID],
         [Name]
order by [ID]
```

You can see the results in this demo in [SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60795/7)

Comment: Thanks for your solution,  this looks like the one I'm able to understand the most. Is it possible to filter on Type  (studentid/employeeid). 
My Orginals db setup looks like this:
- Person ( ID, Name) 
- PersonIdentifications (PersonID, OtherID, Type)?

Comment: if you want to filter out the students you can add a where condition like `where left([Other IDs],1) <> r`(because a student ID begins with 'r'). With your setup you can use the `Type` column to identify the id and put them in the right column

Answer (score 0):

You should study some normalization.

To solve the question use Pivot:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    ID, Name, [Other IDs], row_number() over (partition by ID order by [Other IDs]) rn
  FROM
   (values(1,'John', '22'),(2,'Joe', 'r15'),(2,'Joe','12'),(3,'Jim','17'),(3,'Jim','r87')) 
     x(ID, Name, [Other IDs])
)
SELECT ID, Name, [1] UniqueID, [2] StudentID FROM CTE
PIVOT (max([Other IDs]) FOR [rn] IN ([1], [2])) AS pvt 
ORDER BY ID
```

Result:

```
ID  Name  UniqueID  StudentID
1   John  22        NULL
2   Joe   12        r15
3   Jim   17        r87
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I've seen many examples on Pivot but I'could not figure out how to use it in my case.

Can I add conditions base on Type (studentid/employeeid). My original setup looks like:
- Person ( ID, Name) 
- PersonIdentifications (PersonID, OtherID, Type)